# Display root folder image in Codeigniter view

Tags: php, image, codeigniter

i'm trying to display an image which is located at the root folder of my app, in the same level as the application folder, there is an uploads folder that holds the images. I tried many ways to get there, such as this one:

```
<?php foreach($result as $row): ?>

    <!-- Main Content -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-10 mx-auto">
                <div class="post-preview">

                    <h2 class="post-title">
                        <?php echo $row->title; ?>
                    </h2>
                    <h4 class="post-subtitle">
                        <?php echo $row->calling; ?>
                          <!-- for test pusposes<span>This is the session: //<?php //echo $_SESSION['post_id']; ?></span> -->
                    </h4>

                </a>
                <br />
                <img style="width:100%;" class="img-responsive" src="http://localhost:8888/FintechBlog/uploads/<?php echo $row->img_path; ?>"/>
                <p class="post-meta">
                    <!-- <a href="#">Start Bootstrap</a> -->
                    <p><small>By <?php echo $row->username; ?> |
                        <?php echo time_elapsed_string($row->created); ?></small></p>
                        <p><?php echo $row->body; ?></p>
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Can someone give me some light?
Thank you!!

Comment: have you set your `base_url` in `config.php` file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use it as

```
<img src="<?php echo site_url('uploads/'.$row->img_path;); ?>" />
```

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to do like that

Fist set base  url

```
<base href="<?= site_url() ?>" />
<img src="uploads/imagename.png">
```

Answer (score 0):

try base_url('uploads') it should refer to the folder you wanted